# Restoring RMAN backup in Oracle 9i to another server

Tags: oracle, rman, oracle-9i

I'm trying to do a restore of a cold backup made with rman in Oracle 9i, the question is that I managed to successfully restore the pfile and the controlfile but when I try to give:

```
RMAN> restore database;

Starting restore at [DATE]

allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: sid = 11 devtype = DISK
RMAN-00571: ======================================================================= =============
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ======================================================================= =============
RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at [date]
RMAN-06026: some targets not found - aborting restore
RMAN-06023: no backup or copy of datafile 16 found to restore
RMAN-06023: no backup or copy of datafile 5 found to restore
RMAN-06023: no backup or copy of datafile 2 found to restore
RMAN-06023: no backup or copy of datafile 1 found to restore
```

Physically the backup pieces are there but when I do:

```
list backup of database;
```

it does not show the missing ones.

I must clarify that the restore I'm doing on a different server, but I keep the same directory structure and the same SID as in the original.

Also I copy the backup rman in the same directory.

When this happens in Oracle 11g I simply launch:

```
catalog start with
```

But for 9i there is no such option.

Could you recommend me some solution, please?

The rman script that I use is the following:

```
shutdown immediate;
startup force dba;
shutdown immediate;
startup mount
run {
set command id to 'ORA9';
allocate channel t1 device type disk;
allocate channel t2 device type disk;
allocate channel t3 device type disk;
allocate channel t4 device type disk;
backup filesperset 1
format '/ Backups / FULL_% d_% u'
(
database
include current controlfile
);
release channel t1;
release channel t2;
release channel t3;
release channel t4;
}
alter database open;
```

Would the restore procedure be similar in case the backup is done with tape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I remember, in 9i when rman is doing backup *`"include current controlfile"`* then this controlfile does not contain info about currently processing backup. You can check it by restore this controlfile and issue command:

```
list backup summary;
```

You need to backup your controlfile **after** you do backup of datafiles.

Add `backup current controlfile;`  command before `release channel t1;`
Or configure autobackup of controlfile - I like this option more.

```
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '/Backups/%F';
```

Comment: Oh, ok, I will try that way, I had already lost the hope that they would answer the question, thank you very much, let me try.

Comment: 498/5000
It worked very well!
I modified the script in the following way as suggested:

backup current controlfile; command before release channel t1;

I am very grateful for its solution, it worked perfectly, I did not know that particularity in oracle 9i and it had not occurred to me to do it that way (I did not want to do it with CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON as I was trying a script that I found).

Thank you very much, I had already given up hope that they would answer the question!